# How to get array based on same key value in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have two object arrays `obj1` and `obj2`, how to get the array that matches  key `color-size` of obj1 and `model` of obj2

Below function works, is there alternative way to do

```
getArrayByModel(obj1,obj2){
 return obj2.filter(o1 => obj1.some(o2 => o1.model=== (o2.color+ "-" + o2.size)));
}
console.log(this.getArrayByModel(obj1,obj2));
var obj1 = [
 { id:1, color:"blue",size:"m"}
]

var obj2 = [
 { idx:1, model:"blue-m", store:"111" },
 { idx:2, model:"blue-xs", store: "123"},
 { idx:3, model:"blue-m", store: "345"},
]
```

Expected Output

```
[
 { idx:1, model:"blue-m", store:"111" },
 { idx:3, model:"blue-m", store: "345"}
]
```

Comment: What you have should work.

Comment: When you said "object arrays" - you mean "arrays of objects", which is evident from your code, then `obj1` and `obj2` are actually `arr1` and `arr2` or `objArr1` and `objArr2` - although it won't matter to the computer, it will be easier on the eye and be more "correct" and clear for you and anyone reading the code, for example: using Array methods on `objArrX` and Object methods on `objArrX[key]` or `objArrX.key`.  
(examples of "bad" naming: `integer1="abc"`, `stingArray=true`, etc. = just confusing...)

Answer (score 0):

```
const getArrayByModel = (obj1,obj2) => obj2.filter(o1 => obj1.some(o2 => o1.model === [o2.color, o2.size].join('-')));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `map` and `filter` methods like this:

```js
var obj1 = [
 { id:1, color:"blue",size:"m"}
]

var obj2 = [
 { idx:1, model:"blue-m", store:"111" },
 { idx:2, model:"blue-xs", store: "123"},
 { idx:3, model:"blue-m", store: "345"},
]

var models = obj1.map(x => x.color + '-' + x.size);
var arr = obj2.filter(x => models.indexOf(x.model) > -1);

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obj1 = [
 { id:1, color:"blue", size:"m" },
 { id:2, color:"navy", size:"xl" }
]

var obj2 = [
 { idx:1, model:"blue-m", store:"111" },
 { idx:2, model:"blue-xs", store: "123"},
 { idx:3, model:"blue-m", store: "345"},
 { idx:4, model:"navy-xl", store: "456"},
]

var result = obj2.filter( ( {model, store} ) => {
  return obj1.map( ( {color, size} ) => [color, size].join("-")).includes( model );
} );

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Four alternatives, mostly overkill. But hey, you wanted to know if there were alternatives. The answer is yes. Don't try this at home ;)

```js
const obj1 = [
 { id:1, color:"blue",size:"m"}
]

const obj2 = [
 { idx:1, model:"blue-m", store:"111" },
 { idx:2, model:"blue-xs", store: "123"},
 { idx:3, model:"blue-m", store: "345"},
]

// split to compare
const obj3 = obj2.filter(e => {
  let [color, model] = e.model.split("-");
  return obj1[0].color === color && obj1[0].size === model; 
});

// split to compare one liner
const obj3a = obj2.filter(e => 
  `${e.model.split("-")}` === `${[obj1[0].color, obj1[0].size]}`); 

// reduce
const obj4 = obj2.reduce( (a, e) => (
  `${a.compare.color}-${a.compare.size}` === e.model 
    ? {...a, found: [...a.found, e] }
    : a ), {compare: obj1[0], found: []} 
);

// using the 'thisArg' 
const obj5 = obj2.filter(
  function(e) { return e.model === this[0]; }, 
  [`${obj1[0].color}-${obj1[0].size}`]
);

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj3));
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj3a));
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj4.found));
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj5));
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for giving me a deeper understanding of `reduce`. `prev` cannot be written in the inner function

```js
var obj1 = [
    { id: 1, color: "blue", size: "m" }
]

var obj2 = [
    { idx: 1, model: "blue-m", store: "111" },
    { idx: 2, model: "blue-xs", store: "123" },
    { idx: 3, model: "blue-m", store: "345" },
]

function getArrayByModel(obj1, obj2) {
    const newObj1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj1)),
        newObj2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj2));

    return newObj1.reduce((prev, elem) =>
        prev.concat(newObj2.filter((item) =>
            item.model === `${elem.color}-${elem.size}` && elem
        ))
    , [])
}
console.log(getArrayByModel(obj1, obj2));
```